# Capture key events at system level to control e.g. alsamixer

Tags: linux, keyboard, automation, linux-kernel

In Linux window managers, it is easy to define actions for key events - e.g. in openbox:

> ```
> <keybind key="XF86AudioRaiseVolume">
>   <action name="Execute">
>     <command>amixer set Master 5%+ unmute</command>
>   </action>
> </keybind>
> <keybind key="XF86AudioLowerVolume">
>   <action name="Execute">
>     <command>amixer set Master 5%- unmute</command>
>   </action>
> </keybind>
> ```

But if I want to do the same thing in console mode or would like to enable the same behavior in multiple window managers, I get stuck.

How do I capture keyboard events at system level and trigger scripts that e.g. turn volume up or down?